# rational numbers as upper limit of a summation?

Tags: summation, fractions, rational-numbers

a quick question: Is it a legit way to use a fraction as the upper limit of a summation? Given is a frequency $f$ and a sample rate $f_s$. I want to use a sum like this:

$\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{f_s}{2f}} \sin(2 \cdot \pi \cdot k) $

Is this a legit way to write it?

Comment: A sum of discrete terms only makes sense if you can write them out. Have you tried this with yours?

Comment: My exampe looks like the one given. I can't realy use a different index than k. Any ideas?

Comment: Note that there is no issue if the upper bound can be guaranteed to be a positive integer, I.e. when $f_s = 2nf, n \in \mathbb{Z^+} $. But I'm assuming you're asking about a more general case, in which case, no, having a non-integral upper bound is not meaningful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean to include all the k that are less than $\frac{f_s}{2f}$, you can hedge and use the floor function:

$\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{f_s}{2f}\right\rfloor} \sin(2 \cdot \pi \cdot k) $

This guarantees your bounds are both integers, but contain all the k you want.